# Contents from inDesign extension panels not showing up

Tags: html, plugins, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I tried to follow these guidelines — https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides — to build an extension for Adobe InDesign 2021 (macOS Big Sur). I was able to make my panel (EvoDesigner) show up but no contents appear in it. I also tried to install a sample extension — https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/tree/master/CEP_9.x/Samples/CEP_HTML_Test_Extension-9.0 (also tried it with CEP_10) — but it happens to have the same problem. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

[image: Panels from sample extension and also my panel both showing nothing inside]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by activating debug mode for the other vesions of CSXS I had installed (9 and 10). Turns up, at the time, I had only activated debug mode for version 8, just as exemplified in this [tutorial](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides/tree/master/Client-side%20Debugging#set-the-debug-mode).

So, to solve it, in the terminal (Mac) I typed:

```
defaults write com.adobe.CSXS.8 PlayerDebugMode 1
defaults write com.adobe.CSXS.9 PlayerDebugMode 1
defaults write com.adobe.CSXS.10 PlayerDebugMode 1
```